# Is it possible to create am ssrs report where users can input info into a form, and this data get's written into the database?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have primarily worked with ssrs reports to show reports that just show a view of the data from underlying tables to users by tables/charts. I guess this would be the intended use for ssrs.

However now I need to create a form where users can input data into a form and then this data gets written into a database. If the managers of these users access this same form they can see an approval option to approve what the users inputted. I am not sure if ssrs can do this, and I feel this is getting into the domain of creating web forms/webpages through asp.net.

So firstly is it possible to achieve this task in ssrs, and if not will doing it in asp.net allow me to publish this webpage onto the same server as the ssrs reports?

So far I did find a way to do it in ssrs (https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/8737/SSRS-can-be-also-used-for-user-inputs.html) but it almost looks like a "hack" where we are really using ssrs to do something it is not indented to do and as a result we have no freedom to design the page how we want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes you can but it's *usually* not the best solution.

There are only really two ways you can get inputs into SSRS reports, parameters and actions on report items (cells in a table for example).

If we take a very simple example of a solution to edit an Employees marital status then you could do this by having two parameters, the `EmployeeName` and `Status`. The report's dataset would look something like this.

```
UPDATE Employees SET MaritalStatus = @Status
WHERE EmployeeName = @EmployeeName

SELECT @EmployeeName + ' status was set to ' + @Status As Response
```

Your report would simply have a textbox displaying the Response field.

The other way of doing this would be to keep the report we created above but add a another report to list all the employees and their current status with columns for each available status. By setting an action on the status columns to execute the previous report we created you can pass the employee name and status to the subreport.

Neither of these is ideal and will not allow you to update more than one record at a time but for very simple scenarios where data is seldom updated it's a quick solution.

I've used SSRS for these scenarios previously but invariably I end up building a simple app to do the job. It's got me out of a tight situation often though as you can put something like this together in 20 minutes.

Comment: For the latter solution of building a simple app. What are the requirements to deploy the app? For the reports I have the "Report Manager" web based tool where users can access the reports from there. Do I need SharePoint or some Azure cloud to put the app on there, or is there a way to create it on asp.net and then drop it on the "Report Manager" location.

Comment: I can't really answer that. There are just too many things to consider but basically, you can create your web app using whatever technology you want and then host it. Hosting on the SSRS server itself might be possible if it's running IIS. You could create a report that simply shows links to you web app(s). To get a better informed answer you need to ask a new question and be specific about your aims, SSRS is irrelevant in this scenario so just stick the facts and you'll get a better answer.